# Material-ui App Bar w/ react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I'm wondering how is the proper way to add router links to the material-ui AppBar demo.

https://codesandbox.io/s/l77yj96q7q

I'm new to react and my first guess was to do the navigation programmaticaly (in the click handler for example) but it seems that it isn't the way react-router works.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it programatically by using `this.props.history.push('/My/Route')` in your event handler!  If you don't have access to the history prop, then export your component after currying it with the `WithRouter` component from the React-Router package. Example: `export default WithRouter(MyComponent)`

Or you can wrap a component in the `<Link to='/My/Route'><Component /></Link>` component so that when it's clicked it will route them to the path from the  component.  If you want to retain a component's style, then use the `<NavLink />` component instead of the `<Link />` component.